# ValueError: At least one stride in the given numpy array is negative, and tensors with negative strides are not currently supported

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am writing the code for Autonomous Driving using RL. I am using a stable baseline3 and an open ai gym environment. I was running the following code in the jupyter notebook and it is giving me the following error:

```
# Testing our model
episodes = 5 # test the environment 5 times
for episodes in range(1,episodes+1): # looping through each episodes
    bs = env.reset() # observation space
    # Taking the obs and passing it through our model
    # tells that which kind of the action is best for our work
    done = False 
    score = 0
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action, _ = model.predict(obs) # now using model here # returns model action and next 
state
        # take that action to get the best reward
        # for observation space we get the box environment
        # rather than getting random action we are using model.predict(obs) on our obs for an 
curr env to gen the action inorder to get best possible reward
        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)  # gies state, reward whose value is 1
        # reward is 1 for every step including the termination step
        score += reward
    print('Episode:{},Score:{}'.format(episodes,score))'''
env.close()
```

Error
[image]

[image]

[image]

The link for the code that I have written is given below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JBVmPLn-N1GCl_Rgb6-qGMpJyWvBaR1N/view?usp=sharing

The version of python I am using is Python 3.8.13 in Anaconda Environment.
I am using Pytorch CPU version and the OS is Windows 10.
Please help me out in solving this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `.copy()` for numpy arrays should help (because [PyTorch tensors can't handle negative strides](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/negative-strides-in-tensor-error/134287/2)):

```
action, _ = model.predict(obs.copy())
```

I haven't managed to run your notebook quickly because of dependencies problems, but I had the same error with AI2THOR simulator, and adding `.copy()` has helped.
Maybe someone with more technical knowledge about `numpy`, `torch` or AI2THOR will explain why the error occurs in more detail.